# Why don't the functions work from the modal window?

Tags: reactjs, uikit

The function call does not work when I call it from a modal window. If you take out the button from the modal window in the layout, everything works.

The modal window itself also works (opens, closes) When opened, the "Cancel" button in the modal window works, but this is through the "uk-modal-close" layout class. The modal window is from the UIkit library. There are no errors in the console

I tried to call other functions from the modal window, they do not work.

Code

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import UIkit from 'uikit';

export default class Editor extends Component {
    constructor() {
    super();
    }
    render() {
    const modal = true;
    return (
    <>
        <div className='panel'>
            <button className="uk-button uk-button-primary" onClick={() => console.log("Work!")}>Publish</button> //This code works!
            <button className="uk-button uk-button-primary" uk-toggle="target: #modal-save">Save</button>
        </div>
        <div id="modal-save" uk-modal={modal.toString()}>
            <div className="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-body">
                <h2 className="uk-modal-title">Saving</h2>
                <p className="uk-text-right">
                    <button className="uk-button uk-button-default uk-modal-close" 
                     type="button">Cancel</button>
                    <button className="uk-button uk-button-primary" 
                     onClick={() => this.save()}>Publish</button> //This code doesn`t work!
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
 )
}
```

Option 2

```js
render() {
        const modal = true;
        return (
        <>
            <div className='panel'>
                <button  onClick={() => console.log("Work!")}>Publish</button> //This code works!
                <button  uk-toggle="target: #modal-save">modal</button>  // this is to call a modal window
            </div>
    
            <div id="modal-save" uk-modal={modal.toString()}>
               <button onClick={() => console.log("Work!")}>Publish</button> //This code doesn`t work!
            </div>
        </>
      )
    }
```

Comment: can you show the full code?. Is this a class component || functional and need to see what the save function looks like.

Comment: That's how changed hopefully it will be clearer.  The function the save works well. "console.log" also does not call from the modal window.  Any functions do not work from inside "<div id="modal-save" uk-modal={modal.toString()}></div>".

Answer (score 0):

The issue with this is event delegation in react 17. (https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/10/20/react-v17.html#changes-to-event-delegation)

You will have to use portals.

create a new file called ModalPortal.js and put the following code in it:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
const ModalPortal = (props) => {
  const modalRoot = document.createElement("div");
  modalRoot.setAttribute("uk-modal", "bg-close: false");
  modalRoot.id = "modal-save";

  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.appendChild(modalRoot);
    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(modalRoot);
    };
  });

  return ReactDOM.createPortal(props.children, modalRoot);
};

export default ModalPortal;
```

Then in your main file, replace:

```
<div id="modal-save" uk-modal={modal.toString()}>
    <div className="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-body">
        <h2 className="uk-modal-title">Saving</h2>
        <p className="uk-text-right">
            <button className="uk-button uk-button-default uk-modal-close" 
             type="button">Cancel</button>
            <button className="uk-button uk-button-primary" 
             onClick={() => this.save()}>Publish</button> //This code doesn`t work!
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

with:

```
<ModalPortal>
  <div className="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-body">
    <h2 className="uk-modal-title">Saving</h2>
    <p className="uk-text-right">
      <button
        className="uk-button uk-button-default uk-modal-close"
        type="button"
      >
        Cancel
      </button>
      <button
        className="uk-button uk-button-primary"
        onClick={() => console.log("YES!!")}
        type="button"
      >
        Publish
      </button>{" "}
    </p>
  </div>
</ModalPortal>
```

working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-microservice-oy4os?file=/src/Editor.js

Comment: Thanks! Functions from the modal window work. But I can't understand. The modal window does not open, but after I open or close the developer console (F12) the modal window starts working. Each time after reloading the page, the modal window does not open, after pressing F12 starts working. When I open or close the developer console, changes (props) which is passed to "ModalPortal". I brought it out to the console. After reloading the page -        ModalPortal - props >      {children: {…}} . 
After opening or closing the developer console -     ModalPortal - props >   Object

Comment: Not sure that I understand. Are you talking about your own code or the example I provided? In the example I provided, the modal always pops up when you hit save

Comment: I'm talking about my code. Your code works flawlessly. But when I integrated it into my project there was a problem that I described above. Maybe you know why?

Comment: can you post your updated code that is using portal

Comment: I'm stuck. https://codesandbox.io/live/kuj8lbh  Here I took out a part of the code for an example, but here it works (though sometimes the button of opening of a modal window does not work). I think maybe this is due to the reuse of the component "ModalPortal".
The problem is that sometimes modal windows open and sometimes they don't.
In the example, everything works almost well. 
can I  reuse the component "ModalPortal" for other modal windows?

Comment: Your link does not work for me to look at, can you try again and then share it

Comment: So I'm sorry, apparently after renaming the project, the link stopped working.
Here is the link  https://codesandbox.io/s/3-modal-gjo31

Comment: So what is not working on the example you gave me? I pushed each of the buttons 10+ times and they opened every time